# Azure DevOps pipeline loop, can't find path Powershell script

Tags: powershell, loops, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have this pipeline, which calls a powershell script. The powershell script needs run for each values which is passed into it. So i have created a object in parameters called VariableFiles and mabye a foreach on the steps.

```
pool: 
  vmImage: windows-latest

parameters:
  - name: variableFiles
    displayName: Variable File
    type: object
    default:
      - test
      - testApp
  - name: environment
    displayName: Environment
    type: string
    default: Dev
    values:
      - Dev
      - Test
      - Stag 
      - Prod

variables:
 - group: ADO_statefile 

name: 'ADO Automation'

stages:
- stage: powershellDeployment
  displayName: "PowerShell Deployment"
  jobs:
  - deployment: "deployment"
    displayName: "PowerShell Deployment"
    environment: 'ado - Dev'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - ${{ each variableFile in parameters.variableFiles }}:          
              - template: steps.yml
                parameters:
                  spn: $(service_connection)
                  JsonPath: ${{ variableFile }}
                  validate: true
```

When i have more the 1 object in the variableFiles parameter i get this error:
##[error]The term 'D:\a\1\s\ADO\powershell\CreateAADGroup\createAADGroup.ps1' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.

When I run the same script with just one object in the variableFiles parameter everything works.

I dont really get it.

Here is the steps.yml for template, which is called

```
steps:
  - checkout: self

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "List environment variables"
    inputs:
      pwsh: true
      targetType: "inline"
      script: |
        # List all pipeline variables
        dir env:

  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: "create ADD groups"
    inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.spn }}
        pwsh: true
        azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
        ScriptType: 'FilePath'
        ScriptPath: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ADO/powershell/CreateAADGroup/createAADGroup.ps1"
        ScriptArguments: '-JsonPath ${{ parameters.JsonPath }}'
```

and where is the powershell script:

```
Param(
    [string]$JsonPath
)


$parameters = Get-Content -Raw -Path "$($env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY)\ADO\terraform\$JsonPath.tfvars.json"  | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($GroupName in $parameters.AADGroupName) {
    # Check if the group already exists
    $existingGroup = Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName $GroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
    if ($existingGroup) {
        Write-Host "Group $GroupName already exists. Skipping creation."
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Creating group: $GroupName"
        New-AzADGroup -DisplayName $GroupName -MailNickname $GroupName
    }
}
```

I have tried so many things, move values around and google everything around the subject. I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```yaml
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

as a ScriptPath in your yaml pipeline thus you are receiving term not recognized error.

The predefined variable for Build.SourcesDirectory is `c:\agent_work\1\s` where your source code files are downloaded in the agent, Instead use

```yaml
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

System.DefaultWorkingDirectory will fetch the powershell script and your other files correctly from the root of your repository.

Your updated code should look like:-

```yaml
steps:
  - checkout: self

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "List environment variables"
    inputs:
      pwsh: true
      targetType: "inline"
      script: |
        # List all pipeline variables
        dir env:

  - ${{ each variableFile in parameters.variableFiles }}:
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      displayName: "create ADD groups"
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.spn }}
        pwsh: true
        azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
        ScriptType: 'FilePath'
        ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ADO/powershell/CreateAADGroup/createAADGroup.ps1'
        ScriptArguments: '-JsonPath ${{ variableFile }}'
```

I tried running Get-AzADGroup and New-AzADGroup command by storing them in a script in my repository and used the System.DefaultWorkingDirectory as a script path to the script file and the command and pipeline ran successfully, Refer below:-

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'devopsappsilicon'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/azadgrp1.ps1'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]